# Relation between the eigenvalues of the weighted laplacian and fractional laplacian?

Tags: sp.spectral-theory, laplacian, fractional-calculus

Consider the eigenvalue problem $-\Delta u = \lambda u\rho$ for $u\in \dot{H}^{1}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ with $n\geq 3$ and weight $\rho\in L^{n/2}(\mathbb{R}^n).$ Let $(\lambda_k, \psi_k)$ be the increasing sequence of eigenvalue and eigenfunctions for the above problem.

Now if we consider the problem $(-\Delta)^s u = \gamma u\rho$ with $u\in \dot{H}^s(\mathbb{R}^n)$, $n>2s$, $s \in (0,1)$ and weight $\rho \in L^{n/2s}(\mathbb{R}^n))$ with $(\gamma_k, \phi_k)$ as the increasing sequence of eigenvalues and eigenfunctions, then is true that,

$$\lambda_k = \gamma_k^s,\quad \psi_k = \phi_k?$$

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "eigenvalues for the problem $Lu = u\rho$", but in any case I would not expect such a relation.

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki sorry I made a typo, there should be a scalar there as well.

Comment: If this was true, we would have $\lambda (-\Delta)^s u = \gamma \lambda u \rho = -\gamma \Delta u$. Taking Fourier transforms of both sides leads to $(\lambda |\xi|^s-\gamma|\xi|^2)\hat u(\xi)=0$, and hence $u = 0$ (unless I am missing something).